# A seeming bug on Backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I have a table "companydetails" and I went through your instructions by generating the appropriate items, but when I go to the add I get the following message:

syntax error, unexpected 'stylesheet' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' (View: D:\Laravel\AssociatedLocks\resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\form_content.blade.php) (View: D:\Laravel\AssociatedLocks\resources\views\vendor\backpack\crud\form_content.blade.php)

The problem seems to be the first line of this generated code block:

startSection('after_styles'); ?>
">
">
">
The code on the template that generates this code seems to be OK:

```
@Section('after_styles')  
link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('vendor/backpack/crud/css/crud.css') }}" 
link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('vendor/backpack/crud/css/form.css')}}">
```

(I have had to remove the initial < on the link as the markdown hated it.,

I get this on any create or edit. I am using Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `php artisan view:clear` will fix it for you - it will delete old views from cache.